# Calculate phone bill(python)

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to return to data question is user enters incorrect number.

I need need to know how to return to the question again if incorrect number is entered

```
import math

p=float(input('Please enter the price of the phone: '))
print('')
data=int(input('Enter the amount of the data you will use, 1 gig, 3 gigs, 6 gigs: '))
tax=p*.0925
Total=p+tax
print('')

print ('If your phone cost',p,',the after tax total in Tennessee is',round(Total,2))
print('')
if data==1:
    datap=30
    print('The price of one gig is $30.')
elif data==3:
    datap=45
    print('The price of three gig is $45.')
elif data==6:
    datap=60
    print('The price of six gigs is $60.')
else:
    print(data, 'Is not an option.')
    #I need need to know how to return to the question again if incorrect number is entered

pmt=Total/24
bill=(datap+20)*1.13

total_bill=bill+pmt
print('')
print('With the phone payments over 24 months of $',round(pmt,2),'and data at $',datap,
'a month and line access of $20. Your total cost after tax is $',round(total_bill,2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enter an infinite loop and only break out of it when the user has entered a valid input.

```
import math

costmap = {1: 30, 3: 45, 6: 60}
price = float(input('Please enter the price of the phone: '))
datamsg = 'Enter the amount of the data you will use, 1 gig, 3 gigs, 6 gigs: '

while True:

    try:
        data = int(input(datamsg))
    except ValueError:
        print('must input a number')
        continue

    tax = price * .0925
    total = price + tax

    print('If your phone cost {}, the after tax total in Tennessee is {}'
          .format(price, round(total, 2)))

    try:
        datap = costmap[data]
        print('The price of one gig is ${}.'.format(datap))
        break

    except KeyError:
        print('{} is not an option try again.'.format(data))

pmt = total / 24
bill = (datap + 20) * 1.13
total_bill = bill + pmt

print('With the phone payments over 24 months of ${}'.format(round(pmt, 2)))
print('and data at ${} a month and line access of $20.'.format(datap))
print('Your total cost after tax is ${}'.format(round(total_bill, 2)))
```

You can also simplify your `if/else` clause by defining a dict to map inputs to cost values. If the value does not exist it throws an exception which you can catch, issue an error and go around the loop again.

Finally I'd recommend you try running your code through a pep-8 checker such as http://pep8online.com/. It will teach you how to format your code to make it easier to read. At present your code is more difficult to read than it could be.

Comment: Thanks, I am new to coding and appreciate the help.